# Pagination With Php using Redis DB

Tags: php, pagination, redis

I want to display list of `customers` with `pagination`.Structure of DB is as follow:

```
redis:> hset customerlist username userid (where username:almas userid:1)
redis:> hmset customerlog:1 userid value1 name value2 contactno value3
(where value1:1 , value2: almas sayyad, value3: 8676756556)
```

I have used `hash set` and want to continue with same datatype.
I will be greatfull if any one can give me the solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Paginating a Hash isn't trivial - you should consider using a different data structure that is more suitable for that task, namely the Sorted Set.

Hashes have no order and the only way to sanely iterate their fields is with [`HSCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/hscan). However, scanning is unordered, can return duplicates and the number of results from each call varies - building a pagination mechanism on top of that is challenging and inefficient.

You can keep the data, i.e. users, in a Hash, but store the field names in a Sorted Set as well. You can give each user a score to order them or just use lexicographical ordering - either way, you'll be able to paginate with the Sorted Set.